# Using PostGis BBox and ST_intersects Queries?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, geojson, sql, carto

CartoDb Recommend [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/tips-and-tricks.html) that the following query is faster than an St_intersects Query

```
SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE the_geom && ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(-73.9980, 40.726), ST_Point(-73.995, 40.723)), 4326)
```

I have the following Query that works just fine and returns GeoJson as needed,

```
WITH c AS (SELECT -73.976440429688, 40.743095232182, -73.970947265625, 40.738933241136, 4326 As srid)  ,
bbox AS (SELECT ST_Transform ( ST_MakeEnvelope( -73.976440429688, 40.743095232182 ,-73.970947265625 , 40.738933241136 , 4326) , 900913 ) As geom FROM c )
SELECT row_to_json(fc)
    FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
    FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type, osm_id As id,
        ( SELECT row_to_json(t) 
         FROM (SELECT osm_id, "name" ) t )As properties,
         ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform (lg.way ,4326 ) )::json As geometry 
    FROM planet_osm_polygon As lg, bbox
        WHERE ( building is NOT NULL) AND ST_Intersects(lg.way, bbox.geom)
            ) As f ) fc;
```

I have been trying to create the same JSon result using ST_MakeBox2D in a similar fasion to the CartoDb example and failing miserably.

My objective is to have the fastest possible query for any geometry that any part of itself WITHIN the bounding box.

My Questions are:

1. Which method will return the fastest possible result, assuming that the Columns in the WHERE clause are indexed properly?
2. How do I change my query to use St_makeBox2D with the geom && syntax as per the CartoDb Example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of && will return quicker than ST_Intersects, as it is only checking bounding boxes, which is the first stage of any spatial intersection query, via the bounding boxes stored as part of R-Tree indexing (technically a GIST index in Postgis, but the bounding box is still used in index construction). As, the second stage, the actual intersection is being skipped, you will save time, though this will depend on the complexity of the actual polygons.

You can simply change this line,

```
WHERE building is NOT NULL AND ST_Intersects(lg.way, bbox.geom)
```

to

```
WHERE building is NOT NULL AND lg.way && bbox.geom;
```

in order to just do a bounding box check instead of a full intersects. You can check the relative speed by using the `\timing` switch in psql. Note, however, that because an ST_Intersects query checks the bounding box as part of the calculation, this part of the query will get cached, so you need to clear the query cache to get reliable testing results of ST_Intersects vs &&. This [Stack Exchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216660/see-and-clear-postgres-caches-buffers) has information on clearing the cache.

You can simplify the initial creation of you bbox to one line, as

```
WITH bbox AS (SELECT ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(-73.976440429688, 40.743095232182,
     -73.970947265625, 40.738933241136, 4326), 900913) As geom)
```

which will be exactly the same as using `ST_MakeBox2D(ST_MakePoint(x1, y1), ST_MakePoint(x2, y2)`.

Putting this all together yields,

```
WITH bbox AS 
  (SELECT ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(-73.976440429688, 40.743095232182,
     -73.970947265625, 40.738933241136, 4326), 900913) As geom)
  SELECT row_to_json(fc)
   FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
   FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type, osm_id As id,
    (SELECT row_to_json(t) 
     FROM (SELECT osm_id, "name" ) t )As properties,
     ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform (lg.way ,4326 ) )::json As geometry 
   FROM planet_osm_polygon As lg, bbox
   WHERE ( building is NOT NULL) AND lg.way && bbox.geom
  ) As f 
 ) fc;
```